# Rails Partial Local not Getting Passed Through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of possible options for the `primary_category` for a `blog`.  Each has an associated icon, so I have them in a `blogs/_category_icon.html.erb` partial:

```
<% case @blog.primary_category

 when "General" %>
    <%= link_to blogs_path, class: "text-slate" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-book-open pr-2"></i> <%= @blog.primary_category %>
    <% end %>
  <% when "Motivation" %>
    <%= link_to page_path("motivation"), class: "text-slate" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-mountain pr-2"></i> <%= @blog.primary_category %>
    <% end %>
  <% when "Mindset" %>
    <%= link_to page_path("mindset"), class: "text-slate" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-brain pr-2"></i> <%= @blog.primary_category %>
    <% end %>
  <% when "Resourcing" %>
    <%= link_to page_path("resourcing"), class: "text-slate" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-first-aid pr-2"></i> <%= @blog.primary_category %>
    <% end %>
  <% when "Planning" %>
    <%= link_to page_path("planning"), class: "text-slate" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-sitemap pr-2"></i> <%= @blog.primary_category %>
    <% end %>
  <% when "Time Management" %>
    <%= link_to page_path("time-management"), class: "text-slate" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-stopwatch pr-2"></i> <%= @blog.primary_category %>
    <% end %>
  <% when "Discipline" %>
    <%= link_to page_path("discipline"), class: "text-slate" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-cookie-bite pr-2"></i> <%= @blog.primary_category %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

It renders perfectly on my `blog#show` page with this:

```
<%= render "blogs/category_icon", locals: { blog: @blog } %>
```

However, when I try to call it on the `blogs#index` page from within a `<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>` block it's throwing up an error saying `undefined method 'primary_category' for nil:NilClass`.

The code on the `blogs#index` page is like this:

```
<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
  ...
  <%= render "blogs/category_icon", locals: { blog: blog } %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Can anyone see why this local isn't getting passed through properly?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Then it just says `undefined local variable or method `blog' for #<#<Class:0x00007fd56e3b8d28>:0x00007fd56e3d6b70>
Did you mean?  @blogs`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You need to add the partial option. Try `render partial: ...`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Excellent!  That works on both pages!  If you write it up as an answer I'll happily choose it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [`ActionView/PartialRenderer`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html), you need to use the `partial` option:

```
<%= render partial: "blogs/category_icon", locals: { blog: blog } %>
```

Notice you can also use the option of rendering a collection of partials, but this time using a combination of `collection` and `as` options:

```
<%= render partial: "blogs/category_icon", collection: @blogs, as: :blog %>
```

The iteration through the elements of `@blogs` is handled by Rails.